# How to encode audio to AAC with profile FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, aac

I try to encode audio to AAC with profile `FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW` by the following settings.

```
oc_cxt->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
```

Also from the output of `av_dump_format`, I got this

```
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

But the output is different. Everything is ok, except the output is `AAC`, not `AAC (LC)`. By using `ffprobe` to detect, the output information is

```
$ ffprobe o.m4a
...
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
...
```

`AAC (LC)` is the desired result I need.

But from the command line, `ffmpeg` can generate `AAC (LC)` output. Below is a small test.

```
$ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(440*2*PI*t):d=5" aevalsrc.m4a
$ ffprobe aevalsrc.m4a
...
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
...
```

How can I select `FF_PROFILE_LOW` to get `AAC (LC)` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by new ffmpeg api which I didn't notice.

The extra data need to copy back to `AVStream->codecpar->extradata` after `avcodec_open2`. After that, the ffprobe can detect output is the format I need, `AAC (LC)`.

The following is a code snippet from [ffmpeg.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg.c)

```
if (!ost->st->codecpar->extradata && avctx->extradata) {
    ost->st->codecpar->extradata = av_malloc(avctx->extradata_size + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
    if (!ost->st->codecpar->extradata) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not allocate extradata buffer to copy parser data.\n");
        exit_program(1);
    }    
    ost->st->codecpar->extradata_size = avctx->extradata_size;
    memcpy(ost->st->codecpar->extradata, avctx->extradata, avctx->extradata_size);
}
```

Hopefully it would be helpful to anyone use the latest version of ffmpeg (3.x).

Comment: And to use it ffmpeg 4.x one should replace FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE with AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

Exact same issue happens for me. Thanks for hints & references to copy back the parameters.

New API: `avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, avctx)` should work.

Comment: I can see that this is largely "Thanks". Can you make more obious which part is actually according to [answer]? Because if not, you should just delete this.