# Sync Audio/Video in MP4 using AutoGen FFmpeg library

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg, synchronization, mp4

I'm currently having problems making my audio and video streams stay synced.

These are the AVCodecContexts I'm using:

For Video:

```
AVCodec* videoCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
AVCodecContext* videoCodecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(videoCodec);
videoCodecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
videoCodecContext->width = 1280;
videoCodecContext->height = 720;
videoCodecContext->gop_size = 12;
videoCodecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
videoCodecContext->pix_fmt = videoCodec->pix_fmts[0];
videoCodecContext->codec_id = videoCodec->id;
videoCodecContext->codec_type = videoCodec->type;
videoCodecContext->time_base = new AVRational
{
    num = 1,
    den = 30
};
```

For Audio:

```
AVCodec* audioCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_AAC)
AVCodecContext* audioCodecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(audioCodec);
audioCodecContext->bit_rate = 1280000;
audioCodecContext->sample_rate = 48000;
audioCodecContext->channels = 2;
audioCodecContext->channel_layout = ffmpeg.AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
audioCodecContext->frame_size = 1024;
audioCodecContext->sample_fmt = audioCodec->sample_fmts[0];
audioCodecContext->profile = ffmpeg.FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
audioCodecContext->codec_id = audioCodec->id;
audioCodecContext->codec_type = audioCodec->type;
```

When writing the video frames, I setup the PTS position as follows:

```
outputFrame->pts = frameIndex;  // The current index of the image frame being written
```

I then encode the frame using avcodec_encode_video2().  After this, I call the following to setup the time stamps:

```
ffmpeg.av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet, videoCodecContext->time_base, videoStream->time_base);
```

This plays perfectly.

However, when I do the same for audio, the video plays in slow motion, plays the audio first and then carry's on with the video afterwards with no sound.

I cannot find an example anywhere of how to set pts/dts positions for video/audio in an MP4 file.  Any examples of help would be great!

Also, I'm writing the video frames first, after which (once they are all written) I write the audio.  I've updated this question with the adjusted values suggested in the comments.

I've uploaded a test video to show my results here:  http://www.filedropper.com/test_124

Comment: wrong tag, it must be c++

Comment: I'm using the AutoGen library, which using Invoke in c# to access the libraries!

Comment: I don't use the FFmpeg API, only the compiled **.exe** as a  process (std in/out). Unfortunately I can't test your code but... Let's hope the advice in my answer can be useful to you in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.  I've added a new function to set video/audio positions after setting the frames PTS positions.

Video is just the usual increment (+1 for each frame), whereas audio is done as follows:

```
outputFrame->pts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q(m_audioFrameSampleIncrement, new AVRational { num = 1, den = 48000 }, m_audioCodecContext->time_base);

m_audioFrameSampleIncrement += outputFrame->nb_samples;
```

After the frame is encoded, I call my new function:

```
private static void SetPacketProperties(ref AVPacket packet, AVCodecContext* codecContext, AVStream* stream)
{
    packet.pts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.pts, codecContext->time_base, stream->time_base, AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
    packet.dts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.dts, codecContext->time_base, stream->time_base, AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
    packet.duration = (int)ffmpeg.av_rescale_q(packet.duration, codecContext->time_base, stream->time_base);
    packet.stream_index = stream->index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PS: Check out this article/tutorial on **[A/V Sync with FFmpeg](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html)**. It might help you if the below doesn't.

**1)** Regarding the video & audio timestamps...

Rather than use a current `frameIndex` as the timestamp, and then later **rescaling** them. If possible just skip the rescale.

The alternative would then be to make sure PTS values (in `outputFrame->pts`) are created correctly in the first place by using the video's frames-per-second (FPS). To do this...

**For each Video frame** : `outputFrame->pts = (1000 / FPS) * frameIndex;`
(For a 30 FPS video, frame 1 has 0 time and by frame 30 the "clock" has reached 1 second.
 So 1000 / 30 now gives each video frame a presentation interval of 33.333 msecs. When `frameIndex` is 30 we can say 33.333 x 30 = 1000 m.secs (or 1 second, confirming 30 frames for each second).

**For each Audio frame** : `outputFrame->pts = ((1024 / 48000) * 1000) * frameIndex;`
(since 48khz AAC frame has a duration of 21.333 m.secs, the timestamp increases by that amount of time. The formula is : (1024 PCM / SampleRate) x 1000 ms/perSec) then multiply by frame index).

**2)** Regarding the audio settings...

**Bit-rate :**
`audioCodecContext->bit_rate = 64000;` seems odd if your `sample_rate` is 48000Hz (and I assume, your bit-depth is 16-bits per sample?).

Try either `96000` or `128000` as lowest starting values.

**Frame Size :**

> `int AVCodecContext::frame_size` means "*Number of samples per channel in
>   an audio frame"*.

Considering the above quote of the Docs, and that MPEG AAC does not do "per channel" (since data for both L/R channels is contained within each frame). The AAC frames each hold 1024 PCM samples.

`audioCodecContext->frame_size = 88200;` for size, you could try  `= 1024;`

**Profile :**
I noticed you've used `MAIN` for AAC profile. I'm used to seeing `Low Complexity` in videos. I tried a few random MP4 filess from various sources on my HDD and I cannot find one using "Main" profile. As a last resort, testing "Low Complexity" won't hurt.

Try using `audioCodecContext->profile = ffmpeg.FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;`

PS: Check this for a **[possible AAC issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239113/how-to-encode-audio-to-aac-with-profile-ff-profile-aac-low)** (depending on your FFmpeg version).

Comment: Oops, had forgotten to make my point about a/v timestamps. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a very useful answer.  Need to try it and go from there.

Comment: outputFrame->pts = (1000 / FPS) * frameIndex (for video frames) causes a 19 second video to play fast play in 1 second.

Comment: Can you provide temp link to a sample video file? I'll try check the bytes (to find a fixing value). Try to use 44khz and 128 bitrate. FFmpeg won't make a file when I use your settings, but it auto-defaults to a working fine video using 44100 samplerate + 16-bit depth + 128kbps bit-rate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I've uploaded the video here:  http://www.filedropper.com/test_124